# Make 1shoppingcart process CC orders sent via HTTP from external script

Tags: api, payment-processing

I need to make 1shoppingcart process orders, coming from my script via HTTP (GET or POST).

I would send credit card, and other payment details in XML, JSON, or whatever format is required.

And want 1shoppingCart return results in HTTP response (Error code/text or Success message)

It that possible via some API? Or I will have to "manually" fake the forms submissions to 1SC, and the parse responses to obtain the result?

Answer (score 2):

The 1SC checkout pages are designed to prevent this kind of activity. The API does not provide any method to send orders to the system in any way.

Basically, what you are asking is not possible and attempting to do so would result in having your account closed.

Sorry for the bad news.

Source: QA Analyst for 1SC (ME!)